# After Import of a Userform into VBComponents Properties cannot be read

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I try to import a Userform with:

```
With ownVBProj.VBComponents.Import(FileName:=FName)
  Print #2, FName; " has ", .Properties.Count; " Properties"
End With
```

During execution I get the error

> -2147467259 (80004005) raises (method 'properties' for the object '_VBComponent' has failed)

Although the userform has correctly been imported - I can see it in the formula window.

If I inspect the newly imported component with the object inspector, I can see the property tree, and after I have done this the code can be continued!! Weird.

Does someone has any suggestions to avoid the problem?

**Edit:**

Here is a complete example:

- create a new excel sheet
- insert a userform
- execute the following code:

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim FName As String
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents ' save UserForm1
        With .Item("UserForm1")
            FName = Environ$("Temp") & "\" & .Name & ".frm"
            If (LenB(Dir(FName)) <> 0) Then
                Kill FName
            End If
            .Export Filename:=FName ' rename Form
            .Name = .Name & "_org"
        End With ' import
        With .Import(FName)
            Debug.Print FName; " has ", .Properties.Count; " properties"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the relevant code ?

Comment: Here is a complete example:

create an new excel sheet, insert an userform and execute the following code:  
Sub test()  
Dim FName As String  
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents  
   ' save UserForm1  
   With .Item("UserForm1")  
   FName = Environ$("Temp") & "\" & .Name & ".frm"  
   If (LenB(Dir(FName)) <> 0) Then  
     Kill FName  
   End If  
  .Export Filename:=FName  
  '  rename Form  
 . Name = .Name & "_org"  
End With  
'  import  
With .Import(FName)  
    Debug.Print FName; " has ", .Properties.Count; " properties"  
End With  
End With  
End Sub

Comment: @Burghart Hoffrichter I edited my answer may please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

It is not actually an answer to the problem, but some observation & and may be vague conclusion. I modified the test code and placed the `Debug Print …` statement after `With  .Import` block with a vague idea to ‘Let the VBE 1st finish the import and let it be within the VBComponents collection before querying its property’. And It worked.

```
Sub test()
    Dim FName As String
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents ' save UserForm1
    Debug.Print "UserForm1 has " & .Item("UserForm1").Properties.Count & " properties before"
        With .Item("UserForm1")
        'Debug.Print "UserForm1 has " & .Properties.Count & " properties"
            FName = Environ$("Temp") & "\" & .Name & ".frm"
            If (LenB(Dir(FName)) <> 0) Then
                Kill FName
            End If
            .Export Filename:=FName ' rename Form
            .Name = .Name & "_org"
        End With ' import
        With .Import(FName)
        'Debug.Print FName & " has " & .Properties.Count & " properties"
        End With
        Debug.Print "Userform_org has " & .Item("UserForm1_org").Properties.Count & " properties"
    End With
End Sub
```

I also have another observation. I also tried to count userform1’s property before exporting. I found it is working if only when the Userform1 properties window is active at the instance of running the code. Otherwise the same Error creeps in. I am using Excel 2007. May be it is some kind of bug in VBE.

**Edit2**: wrt 2nd part of my problem, I further observed using  `. Activate` for a particular VBComponent item  prevent the Error. And its properties could be easily accessed. Trying the simple loop below both with and without `Vbc.Activate` line in any excel file containing multiple userForms and modules can demonstrate it.

```
Dim Vbc As VBComponent
    For Each Vbc In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    If Vbc.Type <> 100 Then   ‘ to exclude worksheets
    Vbc.Activate                        ‘  Try with or Without this line 
    Debug.Print Vbc.Name & " has " & Vbc.Properties.Count & " Properties"
    End If
    Next Vbc
```